# Autodesk lmv-visual-reports sample project doesn't work with the latest viewer v2.10.*

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to implement reporting & visualization of colors in the model using Autodesk Viewer somewhat similar to the this [sample application](https://examples.developer.autodesk.com/lmv-visual-reports/) using the source code from https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/lmv-visual-reports.

But it seems that this sample uses the viewer version `1.2.21`. And the version I'm using in my application is the latest viewer `v2.10.*`.

I tried to use the latest viewer `v2.10.*` in this sample application. But it's not working because of the breaking changes in the APIs of the newer version.

It shows this error in the console.

[image]

I've also created an issue in the github repository for this sample application here https://github.com/redcraft/lmv-visual-reports/issues/2. Please check this issue for more details.

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue and make the reporting and the color visualization work in the latest autodesk viewer.

If anyone could offer help, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, indeed it's not working and we're migrating our samples, including this one, but it's not ready.

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Okay. Can you give a rough idea by when those samples will be migrated?